# How to convert a bootable CD ISO image into a bootable DVD

Tags: iso, burning

Is it possible to convert a *bootable* CD ISO image into a *bootable* DVD?
The ISO image in this case is Ubuntu 10.04.2 desktop...

Comment: isn't it the same?, or what do you mean by a dvd iso?

Comment: oops... I should have said just *bootable DVD*... I've modified the question title

Comment: ok, there's no need for a "convertion" of any sorts, if the ISO though intended to be used on a CD, can be burned into a DVD, but honestly that's a waste of a DVD, you are better off downloading the full Ubuntu DVD.

Comment: It's not for me.. I'm helping a friend to set up Ubuntu (on the other side of the planet :), and he only has DVD blanks, but has downloaded the CD iso... and my first test, in `brasero` seemed to reject the disk... but after reading the comments and answer, I've tried it again, and it *works*! .. Thanks to all...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No action should need be taken.  All ISO writing software I have encountered can successfully write a .ISO file intended for CD to DVD, such that the result may be used on devices expecting DVD media, assuming the underlying data is compatible.

My experience is limited to images providing bootable operating systems and media (movies, music) however, so it may be that this will not always be successful: in the limited case of the ISO files distributed by Ubuntu, it should always be true.

Comment: Just as long as you know that you will need to make the DVD drive the to be detectable at the boot stage in BIOS.  Also, burn the disc at the slowest speed possible to obtain the best results for the disc image.