# Can I boot Ubuntu from a 4.7 GB DVD+R?

Tags: boot, partitioning

The title says most, though I need to know because all I have is 4.7 GB DVD+R discs, and I need to boot one to rescue a bricked ASUS laptop. I was trying to install Ubuntu, but I accidentally deleted the Windows partition and had to reboot. The drivers are still there (the keyboard one, at least), but the OS itself was wiped off the disc.

TL;DR: My OS is toast and I need to fix it.

Comment: May be this will help you: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows?_ga=2.50922924.446198140.1517257203-1791765486.1439829564#1

Comment: Are you trying to rescue Windows?

Comment: You can burn the iso (Please search the site if you don't know how to do this. You'll need another computer that works to do this) to a 4.7 g dvd. You can *not* burn it to a 700 mb cd-r. You can also use a 4 gb usb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a bootable CD ISO image into a bootable DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51611/how-to-convert-a-bootable-cd-iso-image-into-a-bootable-dvd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about ISO image size - they [are about 1.5 Gb](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.3/) for desktop variant.
So one normal size 12cm DVD is enough.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto